# Creating a powershell function that will take on ONE parameter and outputs a concatenated string value (fname+lname)

Tags: string, powershell, function, parameter-passing, string-concatenation

I'm looking for some guidance or tips for how to revise the function below. My goal is create a function that accepts one parameter and then returns a string. In this case the string will be a name of a super hero. The catch is that the function must output the  full name concatenated together (ex. $FullName = $FName + "" +$LName). Can anyone give me some guidance on how I can accomplish this?

So far a have functional function that accepts one parameter but the output is the full name as one singular string. I am unable to find away to concatenate a first and last name and use it as my single parameter for this function. The commented out section of the function is just some trial and error code that I have attempted so far. Any help is appreciated!

The strings I'm working with:

Bat Man,
Wonder Woman,
Aqua Man

```
 function Get-DCHero {
    
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param (
    
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateSet('Batman','Superman','Aquaman','Wonder Woman',ErrorMessage = "'{0}' is not a DC Super Hero. Please trying one of the following: '{1}'")]
            [string]$Name
    
    <#
    
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateSet('Batman','Superman','Aquaman','Wonder Woman',ErrorMessage = "'{0}' is not a DC Super Hero. Please trying one of the following: '{1}'")]
            [string]$FullName = $FName + "" +$LName
    
            [ValidateSet('Bat','Super','Aqua','Wonder','Flash',ErrorMessage = "'{0}' is not a DC Super Hero. Please trying one of the following: '{1}'")]
            [string]$FName
    
            [ValidateSet('Man','Man','Man','Woman','Flash',ErrorMessage = "'{0}' is not a DC Super Hero. Please trying one of the following: '{1}'")]
            [string]$LName
    
    #>
    
        )
    
            Write-OutPut "$Name is a DC Super hero."
    
    }
```

Comment: did you ask this yesterday?

Comment: this is possible but you'd have to request first and last name from the user OR test the input to see if the first name matched a whole first name from the list. like `$_ doesn't match any heroes. Please try using Get-DCHero -fname name1 -lname name2 for better results.`

Comment: Please clarify whether you want to stick with _one_ parameter and simply perform the concatenation when you _pass an argument_ to that one parameter (`Get-DCHero -Name ('Super' + 'Man')`, or whether you want _two_ parameters. If the latter, you can simply output `$FName + $LName`

Comment: @anothervictimofthemouse I did not ask this yesterday. I did have another question from yesterday using this same function however. How would I test the input for if the whole first or last match the first and last name from the list?

Comment: @mklement0 I'm just going off of the instructions that I was given. I would need to stick with 1 paramater.

Comment: So if `Get-DCHero -Name ('Super' + 'Man')` doesn't solve your problem, it is still unclear what your problem is.